# Is there a way in Kotlin to create/initiolise an multidimensional array without giving it values

Tags: kotlin, multidimensional-array

Hi I want to know if there is a short way to create an multidimensional array without preassinde values like in C# `string[][] arr = string[5][]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string[][] arr = string[5][]` in C# is not a multidimensional array, nor does it not have "preassigned values". It is a *jagged array* (this means that each inner array can be a different length), and has `null` as the initial (preassigned) values for each inner array.

To do the same in Kotlin, you'd do:

```
val arr = arrayOfNulls<Array<String?>>(5)
```

This gives you a `Array<Array<String?>?>`. I would imagine having the inner array being nullable can be quite inconvenient sometimes.

If you just want a n by m array, but want the elements `null` by default, you can do:

```
val arr = Array(5) { arrayOfNulls<String>(10) }
```

This roughly translates to this in C#:

```
var arr = new string[5, 10];
```